# how can I get uri of a file that located in assets

Tags: java, android, android-videoview

how can I get uri of a file that located in assets. is there any way to get uri for a asset file?

Comment: Have you tried `getResources().getAssets().list("")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "absolute path for a file existing in the asset folder".

You can use [AssetManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html) object to get an InputStream

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
String path = "file:///android_asset/file_name.mp3";

Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);
```

Comment: i think it only works for webview, not for normal native approach

Answer (score 0):

you can get by this way::

```
file:///android_asset/xyz.mp3
or
file:///android_asset/xyz.txt
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"HandmadeTypewriter.ttf");
```